# readline for Octave - move cursor with mouse

Tags: octave, readline

I have recently downloaded Octave 3.8.0/ 4.0.3 (using MacPorts) in my  Mac EI Captain 10.11. However I realised I am unable to amend my code flexibly in octave.

For example for this code "1 / ( 1 + exp(-5))", if using my mouse I tried to place my cursor before "exp" and try deleting the codes prior to "exp", I am unable to do so. To amend this code, I can only make use of my keyboard arrow keys to go back from the end of the code, until it reaches before "e", then only I am able to delete my code.

This is so frustrating. Downloading a more recent Octave version doesn't help as well. Tried researching online but cant find any workable solutions as well.

Will appreciate any help.

Comment: Octave uses readline so what it supports and how it behaves is dependent on your readline version and your configuration of it.

Comment: will u mind elaborating further? how can i configure readline properly? i tried downloading the latest readline version from https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/readline/ but that does not help too.. :(

Comment: I’ve been looking for a while for a way to get Readline to work with my mouse. I’m not sure it’s possible, but if you found something I’d appreciate it if you came back to answer this.